# How to Run angular 2 app using Ctrl+f5 in visual studio 2015

Tags: node.js, angular

i am creating an Angular 2 application using Visual Studio 2015 and i want to run App directly Ctrl+f5 by changing configuration but i failed.

Comment: You have also failed to show us what you have tried to make this happen. Please, include that in the question.

Comment: I want to run Angular App to shortcut key